# Laravel cannot find it's automatically generated database tables

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, homestead

I am setting up a new Laravel project inside the homestead, and the autogenerated login stuff does not work after I used the `PHP artisan make:auth` command. I have not edited any of the files, and I left the database name as default in my homestead.yaml. The actual error is

```
    SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = <email I used>)
```

I've tried restarting homestead, rerunning the command, and restarting my pc.  I am not sure what else I could do since the autogenerated stuff should work from the start.

In my .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

In homestead.yaml:

```
databases:
- homestead
```

In my database/migrations I have the autogenerated files.
I have not touched config/auth.php or config/database.php.

I expected it to register a user or login correctly. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you already done

```
php artisan make:auth
```

you need to run

```
php artisan migrate
```